# Sort list of below dictionary in descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I have the below dictionary and i want sorted dictionary

```
dict1 = {'years': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'working': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'experience': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'I': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'T': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'associated': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'different': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'organizations': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'His': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 1}], 'work': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'domain': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'area': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'financial': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'Project': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'Manager': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'He': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'areas': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'major': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'patient': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 2}, {'doc_3': 0}], 'billing': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'assessments': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'radiation': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'endoscopy': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 1}, {'doc_3': 0}],
     'interest': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 1}],
     'data': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 3}], 'science': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 2}],
     'favorite': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 1}], 'book': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 1}],
     'big': [{'doc_1': 0}, {'doc_2': 0}, {'doc_3': 1}]}
```

I want to sort value wise i.e
The document has highest value print first then lower and don't print  0 value document.

Comment: Where did you get stuck at exactly?

Comment: Please read up on [how to post a proper question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Stackoverflow is not meant to be a site where someone can do what you need. Please show the following: 1. what you have done so far? 2. what was the output of that? 3. What was the expected output?

Comment: Thanks @yatu for your response! The document(doc_1, doc_2, doc_3) has highest value print first then lower and don't print 0 value document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution:

```
d = {}
for key,list_dict in dict1.items():
    d[key]  = sorted([k for k  in list_dict if list(k.items())[0][1] >0], key=lambda x: list(x.items())[0][1], reverse=True)

d
```

Output:

```
{'He': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'His': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_3': 1}],
 'I': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'Manager': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'Project': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'T': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'area': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'areas': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'assessments': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'associated': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'big': [{'doc_3': 1}],
 'billing': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'book': [{'doc_3': 1}],
 'data': [{'doc_3': 3}],
 'different': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}],
 'domain': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}],
 'endoscopy': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'experience': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'favorite': [{'doc_3': 1}],
 'financial': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}],
 'interest': [{'doc_3': 1}],
 'major': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'organizations': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'patient': [{'doc_2': 2}],
 'radiation': [{'doc_2': 1}],
 'science': [{'doc_3': 2}],
 'work': [{'doc_1': 1}],
 'working': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}],
 'years': [{'doc_1': 1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:-

```
res = {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
    res[key] = [i for i in dict1[key] if 0 not in (i.values())]
    res[key] = sorted(res[key], key=lambda x : x[list(x.keys())[0]], reverse=True)

print(res)
```

Output:-

```
{'years': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'working': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}], 
 'experience': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'I': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'T': [{'doc_1': 1}], 
 'associated': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'different': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}], 
 'organizations': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'His': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_3': 1}], 
 'work': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'domain': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}], 
 'area': [{'doc_1': 1}], 'financial': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 1}], 
 'Project': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'Manager': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'He': [{'doc_2': 1}], 
 'areas': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'major': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'patient': [{'doc_2': 2}], 
 'billing': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'assessments': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'radiation': [{'doc_2': 1}], 
 'endoscopy': [{'doc_2': 1}], 'interest': [{'doc_3': 1}], 'data': [{'doc_3': 3}], 
 'science': [{'doc_3': 2}], 'favorite': [{'doc_3': 1}], 'book': [{'doc_3': 1}], 
 'big': [{'doc_3': 1}]
}
```

Comment: thanaks for your response. check this                 
dict1 = {'years': [{'doc_1': 1}, {'doc_2': 3}, {'doc_3': 0}]}
res = {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
    res[key] = [i for i in dict1[key] if 0 not in (i.values())]
    res[key] = sorted(res[key], key=lambda x : x[list(x.keys())[0]])

print(res)

Comment: @AliZaib, Thanks for pointing out, I  have updated the code. Now it should work.

Comment: thanks for your and code working fine now. But i have already mark the answer. I don't have another option to mark your answer too. I want  to mark but i don't have option. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, I know one can accept only one answer on StackOverflow. If you want, you can upvote my answer instead. Thanks @AliZaib

Comment: I had marked his answer before you commented. You both deserve the green tick but i don't have option. I want to tick your answer but I also don't want something wrong.